# Caching of anonymous objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, memory-address, object-lifetime

This is a nonsensical example used purely for illustration purposes:

```
function a() {
  return b().bar + foo.bar;
}

function b() {
  var foo = {
    bar: 'baz'
  };
  return foo;
}

console.log(a()); // Obviously throws a Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined.
```

What I would like to understand is:

1) Is `foo` resolved as an anonymous object (`Object {bar: "baz"}`) in `function b` before returning? Or is it resolved in `function a` after `foo` is returned?

2) Since the return value of the `b()` call is cached temporarily in order to execute the string concatenation, would it be possible to access that anonymous object during run time, like I tried? Well, it's obviously not called "foo" anymore, but it's temporarily in the scope of `function a`, so the function scope knows of it's location, right?

For example:

```
function a() {
  return b().bar + b().bar;
}

function b() {
  var foo = {
    bar: 'baz'
  };
  return foo;
}

console.log(a()); // logs "bazbaz".
```

Which means the result of the first `b()` call is stored somewhere on the stack until the second one returns. Is it possible to refer to this object directly during run-time?

Comment: The name foo only exists inside your the scope of `function b`. The name is meaningless outside of that function.

Comment: All objects are "anonymous" in JavaScript. There is no general concept of an object having a name.

Comment: _Is it possible to refer to this object directly during run-time?_ `var foo2 = b();` as far as I'm aware it'll be pointing to the same object as the object that's created in the `b` function, objects are passed by reference in JS.

Comment: @George: Be careful there, "pass by reference" is a term of art referring **specifically** to passing references to *variables* into functions. JavaScript doesn't have pass by reference at all. The *value* passed into and out of functions related to objects is called an object reference, but that's a completely different use of the word "reference."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What's the difference if you don't mind explaining? Other than one is a decision to pass by reference made by the programmer and the other is just how the JS engine handles objects.

Comment: @George: Different functionality. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952217/157247), which is for Java but JavaScript is the same in this regard.

Comment: @George
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880418/javascript-pass-object-as-reference is also quite relevant and illustrates the difference pretty well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, I think I get it now, JS object reference is more of a copy of the reference rather than directly passing the reference, so although _similar_ it is different.  I'll have to read more on it rather than asking questions here and polluting the comments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Is `foo` resolved as an anonymous object (`Object {bar: "baz"}`) in function `b` before returning? Or is it resolved in function `a` after `foo` is returned?

The identifier `foo` exists only within `b`. When you do `return foo`, `foo`'s value is resolved and then set as the return value of `b` (whereupon that value no longer has any connection back to the identifier).

> 2) Since the return value of the `b()` call is cached temporarily in order to execute the string concatenation, would it be possible to access that anonymous object during run time, like I tried?

Not directly, you'd have to store that value somewhere in order to reuse it:

```
function a() {
  var bval = b();
  return bval.bar + bval.bar;
}
```

> Which means the result of the first `b()` call is stored somewhere on the stack until the second one returns. Is it possible to refer to this object directly during run-time?

No, you can't directly access the stack.